# how to share data between django server and python websocket server

Tags: python, django, memory, python-sockets, shared-variable

I am writing a web app with Django in which I have to share some data with another python socket server running in parallel.

I have tried using a common python file to store global variable.
but since those server are two different processes it is not working.
(I am not interested in using any database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use main file that starts up both services either with the libraries threading or multiprocessing and just communicate with normal python data types.

If these two services have to be separate programs then you would need to design an API for them to communicate and use sockets or some library build on-top of sockets to communicate.